# Azure Active Directory - Navigation items like 'Users and groups' disappear when I enter the application page

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I created a native app in Azure AD and I can't add users to it, because when I click the app, some navigation items (including Users and Groups) appear for a split second then disappear. How do I add users to the app?

[image: Screenshot of AD menu]
[image: Screenshot of AD menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with Azure Power Shell.

```
$appId = "your native app application id"
$user = Get-AzureADUser -searchstring "<Your user's UPN>"
$servicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $servicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id ([Guid]::Empty)
```

Then, you could find the user on Azure Portal.

[image]

Note: Currently, it is not possible add users to native app on Azure Portal.

Comment: Was that changed only in the last few days? I added a user last week...

Comment: It doesn't work. I get `New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is null`